# Google Sheets API not returning result in PhoneGap app

Tags: javascript, api, cordova, google-sheets-api, phonegap

I have a webpage that I want to turn into a phonegap app.

It works properly on the website, running on `localhost:3002`, fetching the data from the Google sheets. But its not working on the IP address(and the PhoneGap developer app on android) that was provided by the phonegap CLI which is `192.168.1.43:3002`.

On running on `192.168.1.43:3002`, it logs the following error in the console:

```
GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframerpc?action=listSessions&scope=op…n=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.43%3A3002&origin=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.43%3A3002 400 ()
```

I have added both the IP address & `localhost:3002` in the Google developers console under *Authorized JavaScript origins*.

HTML file:

```
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

  <script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxx&libraries=geometry">
  </script>

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
  ...
```

This is the JS file:

```
  ...

  function start() {
    var sheetId = 'xxxxxxxxx';

    // 2. Initialize the JavaScript client library.
    gapi.client.init({

      'apiKey': googleApiKey,

      'clientId': 'xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'

    }).then(function() {

      // 3. Initialize and make the API request.
      return gapi.client.request({
        'path': 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'+sheetId+'/values/A:F'
      });

    }).then(function(response) {

      console.log(response);

      createplacesList(response.result.values);

    }, function(reason) {

      console.log('Error: ' + reason.result);

    });
  }

  // 1. Load the JavaScript client library.
  gapi.load('client', start);

  ...
```

**What's causing it to work on `localhost` and not on the IP address(also PhoneGap developer app)?**

Comment: Maybe its not whitelisted?

Comment: @Webbanditten well it shows that it is. How else can I check it? Any suggestions ?

Comment: I haven't been able to get it to work either. I'm debating on using AJAX to see if that works.